# python insert or update order of list items

Tags: python

i have a python code which returns a list of dictionaries, similar to:

```
[{'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'S', 'sku': 'EP01-RE1'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'M', 'sku': 'EP01-RE2'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'L', 'sku': 'EP01-RE3'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'XL', 'sku': 'EP01-RE4'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': '2XL', 'sku': 'EP01-RE5'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'XS', 'sku': 'EP01-RE0'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': '3XL', 'sku': 'EP01-RE6'}]
```

what would be the correct way to sort this, so that i get, `XS` come befre `S`:

```
0 S
1 M
2 L
3 XL
4 2XL
5 XS
6 3XL
7 4XL
8 5XL
```

i have entries with `XXS`

the code i have:

```
for idx, size in enumerate(sizes):
    size_short_name = size.get('sizeCode')
    print idx, size_short_name
```

the only way, i can think of is to, create a new list of sizes and if size code is XS, then add this to the begging and so on.

any advice much appreciated.

Comment: `XS` is extra small, should that not be first?

Comment: You will need to define a way to tell Python which order the sizes should be in, e.g. `sizes = {'XS': 0, 'S': 1, ...}`, then use that to get the appropriate number to sort on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting with a custom sort key does the trick

```
def sort_key(item):
    code = item['sizeCode']

    # Get the index for S, M and L where S is -1 and L is 1
    a = 'SML'.index(code[-1]) - 1

    # Get the X, 2X, 3X
    if code[0].isdigit():
        b = int(code[0])
    elif code[0] == 'X':
        b = 1
    else:
        b = 0

    return a, a * b

print sorted(sizes, key=sort_key)
```

Result:

```
[{'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'XS', 'sku': 'EP01-RE0'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'S', 'sku': 'EP01-RE1'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'M', 'sku': 'EP01-RE2'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'L', 'sku': 'EP01-RE3'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': 'XL', 'sku': 'EP01-RE4'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': '2XL', 'sku': 'EP01-RE5'},
 {'colourCode': 'RE', 'sizeCode': '3XL', 'sku': 'EP01-RE6'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping from size string to sort order:

```
sizes = {'XS': 0, 'S': 1, 'M': 2, ...}
```

then use that in your sort key:

```
sorted(inputlist, key=lambda entry: sizes.get(entry.get('sizeCode'), float('inf')))
```

I used a default of `float('inf')` to put any missing or unrecognised sizes at the very end. Use `'-inf'` if you want those at the start instead.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your data, and assuming there is some logic to the sku numbers, you can just use that as a key with

```
sorted(inputlist, key = lambda entry : entry["sku"])
```

This assumes a consistent approach to defining sku's, such as "EP01" repesents the clothing item, and "REn" represents the size. But this will fail once you have more than 10 sizes.

It will also have the advantage that, as the input list contains more clothing items, the results will be sorted both by size and item.

Comment: Anychance of a reason for the downvote so I can adjust my answer?